# Calculating a limit of a sequence of integrals that approaches the catalan constant

Tags: real-analysis, limits, improper-integrals, uniform-convergence, catalans-constant

> Let $f\colon[0, 1] \to \mathbb{R}$, $f(x)=\frac{\arctan(x)}{x}, x \in (0, 1], f(0)=1$. Prove that $$\lim_{n \to \infty} n \left(\frac{\pi}{4}-n\int_0^1\frac{x^n}{1+x^{2n}}dx \right)=\int_0^1f(x)dx$$

My approach was to make the change of variables $u=x^n, \text{ which is bijective on [0, 1]. Therefore } x=u^{\frac{1}{n}} \implies dx=\frac{1}{n}u^{\frac{1}{n}-1}; \frac{\pi}{4}=\int_0^1\frac{1}{1+x^2}dx$. Now we rewrite the requested limit:
$$n \left(\frac{\pi}{4}-n\int_0^1\frac{x^n}{1+x^{2n}}dx \right)=n \left(\int_0^1\frac{1}{1+u^2}du-\int_0^1\frac{u^{\frac{1}{n}}}{1+u^{2}}dx \right)=\int_0^1\frac{-\frac{u^{\frac{1}{n}}-1}{\frac{1}{n}}}{1+u^2}du$$.

My question is now can we interchange the limit with the integral? $\frac{u^h-1}{h}$ approaches $\ln(u)$ when $h$ approaches $0$, so it would make sense that
$$\lim_{n \to \infty}\int_0^1\frac{-\frac{u^{\frac{1}{n}}-1}{\frac{1}{n}}}{1+u^2}du=\int_0^1\frac{-\ln(u)}{1+u^2}du$$.

Now if we do integration by parts on $\int_0^1f(x)dx$ we obtain$$\int_0^1f(x)dx=\arctan(x)\ln(x)\mid_0^1-\int_0^1\frac{\ln(x)}{1+x^2}dx=\int_0^1\frac{-\ln(u)}{1+u^2}du$$

I have not yet learned in school about uniform convergence, but I read by myself that if a sequence of functions is uniformly convergent to some function, then we can interchange the limit. Is it true that $\frac{u^h-1}{h}$ converges uniformly to $\ln(u)$? It seems obvious, but I can't seem to prove it, since $u=0$ makes the function behave badly. But again $u=0$ is the only problem, it is only one point of discontinuity so it should not influence the value that much.

I do not know if this is relevant, but I looked up and found that $\int_0^1f(x)dx$ is the catalan constant.

Any help in solving this problem regarding the interchange of limits would be gladly appreciated.

Comment: wow what a problem! 

Comment: +1 for putting up such a nice question with all the details.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The convergence $n \left(1 - u^{1/n} \right)\to -\ln(u)$ as $n \to \infty$ is not uniform for $u \in (0,1]$ since

$$\sup_{u \in (0,1]} \left|n \left(1 - u^{1/n} \right) -\ln(u) \right| = +\infty \underset{n \to \infty}\longrightarrow +\infty \neq 0$$

Nevertheless, you can interchange the limit and integral by the monotone convergence theorem since for each fixed $u \in [0,1]$ we have that
$f(h,u) = \frac{1 - u^h}{h}$ is nondecreasing as $h \to 0+$.

**Alternative Approach**

Note that

$$\tag{1}D_n= \left|\int_0^1\frac{n(1-u^{1/n})}{1+u^2}\,du-\int_0^1\frac{-\ln(u)}{1+u^2}\,du\right| \\=  \left|\int_0^\epsilon\frac{n(1-u^{1/n})}{1+u^2}\,du+\int_\epsilon^1\frac{n(1-u^{1/n})}{1+u^2}\,du-\int_\epsilon^1\frac{-\ln(u)}{1+u^2}\,du- \int_0^\epsilon\frac{-\ln(u)}{1+u^2}\,du\right|\\ \leqslant \underbrace{\left|\int_\epsilon^1\frac{n(1-u^{1/n})}{1+u^2}\,du-\int_\epsilon^1\frac{-\ln(u)}{1+u^2}\,du \right|}_{A(n,\epsilon)}+ \underbrace{\left|\int_0^\epsilon\frac{n(1-u^{1/n})}{1+u^2}\,du\right|}_{B(n,\epsilon)} + \underbrace{\left|\int_0^\epsilon\frac{-\ln(u)}{1+u^2}\,du\right|}_{C(\epsilon)}$$

Since $n(1- u^{1/n}) \to -\ln(u)$ monotonically as $n \to \infty$ for each $u \in (0,1]$ we can bound the second and third terms on the RHS of (1) (uniformly for all $n$) as

$$0 \leqslant B(n, \epsilon) \leqslant C(\epsilon)= \int_0^\epsilon\frac{-\ln(u)}{1+u^2}\,du\leqslant \int_0^\epsilon-\ln(u) \, du = \epsilon - \epsilon \ln(\epsilon)$$

It follows from (Arzela's) bounded convergence theorem for Riemann integrals that $$\lim_{n \to \infty} A(n,\epsilon) = 0$$

Hence, for all $\epsilon > 0$ we have

$$\tag{2}0 \leqslant \liminf_{n \to \infty} D_n \leqslant \limsup_{n \to \infty}D_n \leqslant  \lim_{n \to \infty} A(n,\epsilon) + 2(\epsilon - \epsilon \ln (\epsilon))= 2(\epsilon - \epsilon \ln (\epsilon))$$

Since, the RHS of (2) can be arbitrarily small  it follows that

$$\liminf_{n \to \infty} D_n = \limsup_{n \to \infty}D_n = \lim_{n \to \infty}D_n = 0,$$

and

$$\lim_{n \to \infty}\int_0^1\frac{n(1-u^{1/n})}{1+u^2}\,du=\int_0^1\frac{-\ln(u)}{1+u^2}\,du$$

Comment: Would you mind elaborating on the monotone convergence theorem? I have looked it up and it seems to say that if $f_n$ is a sequence of Lebesgue integrable functions such that $f_n(x) \leq f_{n+1}(x), \forall n$, and $f_n$ converges pointwise to $f$ then the limit of the integral of $f_n$ is equal to the integral of $f$. If $g$ is Riemann integrable, then $g$ is also Lebesgue integrable.But this exercise assumes only the knowledge of Riemann integrals. Is it possible to solve it only using Riemann integration and/or convergence of sequences of functions(in metric spaces)?

Comment: Even if you want to avoid the concept of a Lebesgue integral, bear in mind that you are not dealing simply with a Riemann integral here but rather an improper integral.  The limit function $\ln(u)$ is not bounded on $(0,1]$ and, therefore, is not Riemann integrable.    Of course, $\int_0^1 \ln(u) \, du = -1$ as a convergent improper integral.   I can get back to you shortly on this.  But be clear about what you expect to see in terms of justifying the interchange. You can't simply operate in the realm of Riemann integration.

Comment: @Shthephathord23: I added a proof that works entirely within the framework of Riemann integration.

Answer (score 1):

I you feel comfortable with the Gaussian hypergeometric function and generalized harmonic numbers
$$\int \frac{x^n}{1+x^{2 n}}\,dx=\frac{x^{n+1}}{n+1}\, _2F_1\left(1,\frac{n+1}{2 n};\frac{3 n+1}{2 n};-x^{2 n}\right)$$
$$\int_0^1 \frac{x^n}{1+x^{2 n}}\,dx=\frac 1{4n}\left(H_{\frac{1-n}{4 n}}-H_{\frac{1-3 n}{4 n}}\right)$$ Using asymptotics and the definition of Catalan number
$$\text{lhs}=C-\frac{\pi ^3}{32 n}+O\left(\frac{1}{n^2}\right)$$ while the rhs is just $C$.